# Does $A x > b$ have a solution?

Tags: linear-programming, decision-problems

> Formulate a linear program that will determine whether or not $Ax>b$ has a solution, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m$-vector.

We were told to use Farkas Lemma, but are not sure how to deal with strict inequalities. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Edits: 
I understand Farkas' Lemma as a theorem whereby only one of the following two conditions hold:

1. Either the vector $b$ $\in$ cone($a_1$,...,$a_n$)
2. The vector $b$ and cone($a_1$,...,$a_n$) can be separated by a hyperplane through the origin

I am trying to rewrite $A x > b$ in standard form to apply the variant of the Farkas' lemma:
*$A x = b$, $x \geqslant 0$ has a solution iff $A^Ty \geqslant 0$ , and $y^Tb \geqslant 0$*

My initial steps:
$A x - et \geqslant b$ has a sol iff
$A (x^+-x^-)-et-s = b$,  $x^+,x^-,s,t \geqslant 0$
$$
    \left[\begin{matrix}
    A & -A & -e & -I  
    \end{matrix}\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
    x^+ \\ x^- \\ t \\ s
    \end{matrix}\right] = b
$$

Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: consider the system $Ax+ye \geq b, y \in \mathbb{R}$ where $e$ is the all-1 vector.

Comment: @LinAlg thanks for the response. I did that, but to convert it to standard form for applyong Farkas, do I still need to add a slack? Thank you!

Comment: What is your definition of Farka's Lemma?

Comment: @Math1000 I have edited in the question. Thank you.